# Whats wrong with installing facebooker rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oauth, facebooker, authlogic-oauth

I try to install rails facebooker to my authlogic gems from here https://github.com/kalasjocke/authlogic_facebook_connect, but if  sudo gem install facebooker
i get

```
from /home/pavel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:215:in `resolve'
        from /home/pavel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:336:in `block in resolve_requirement'
        from /home/pavel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:335:in `catch'
        from /home/pavel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:335:in `resolve_requirement'
        from /home/pavel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:287:in `block in resolve'
        from /home/pavel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:286:in `reverse_each'
        from /home/pavel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:286:in `resolve'
        from /home/pavel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:336:in `block in resolve_requirement'
        from /home/pavel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:335:in `catch'
        from /home/pavel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:335:in `resolve_requirement'
        from /home/pavel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:287:in `block in resolve'
        from /home/pavel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:286:in `reverse_each'
        from /home/pavel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:286:in `resolve'
        from /home/pavel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:215:in `resolve'
        from /home/pavel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:336:in `block in resolve_requirement'
        from /home/pavel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:335:in `catch'
        from /home/pavel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:335:in `resolve_requirement'
        from /home/pavel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:287:in `block in resolve'
        from /home/pavel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:286:in `reverse_each'
        from /home/pavel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:286:in `resolve'
        from /home/pavel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:336:in `block in resolve_requirement'
        from /home/pavel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:335:in `catch'
        from /home/pavel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:335:in `resolve_requirement'
        from /home/pavel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:287:in `block in resolve'
        from /home/pavel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:286:in `reverse_each'
        from /home/pavel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:286:in `resolve'
        from /home/pavel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:215:in `resolve'
        from /home/pavel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:215:in `resolve'
        from /home/pavel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:336:in `block in resolve_requirement'
        from /home/pavel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:335:in `catch'
        from /home/pavel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:335:in `resolve_requirement'
        from /home/pavel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:287:in `block in resolve'
        from /home/pavel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:286:in `reverse_each'
        from /home/pavel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:286:in `resolve'
        from /home/pavel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:336:in `block in resolve_requirement'
        from /home/pavel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:335:in `catch'
        from /home/pavel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:335:in `resolve_requirement'
        from /home/pavel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:287:in `block in resolve'
        from /home/pavel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:286:in `reverse_each'
        from /home/pavel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:286:in `resolve'
        from /home/pavel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:215:in `resolve'
        from /home/pavel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:215:in `resolve'
        from /home/pavel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:215:in `resolve'
        from /home/pavel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:336:in `block in resolve_requirement'
        from /home/pavel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:335:in `catch'
        from /home/pavel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:335:in `resolve_requirement'
        from /home/pavel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:287:in `block in resolve'
        from /home/pavel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:286:in `reverse_each'
        from /home/pavel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:286:in `resolve'
        from /home/pavel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:215:in `resolve'
        from /home/pavel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:336:in `block in resolve_requirement'
        from /home/pavel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:335:in `catch'
        from /home/pavel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:335:in `resolve_requirement'
        from /home/pavel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:287:in `block in resolve'
        from /home/pavel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:286:in `reverse_each'
        from /home/pavel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:286:in `resolve'
        from /home/pavel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:215:in `resolve'
        from /home/pavel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:336:in `block in resolve_requirement'
        from /home/pavel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:335:in `catch'
        from /home/pavel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:335:in `resolve_requirement'
        from /home/pavel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:287:in `block in resolve'
        from /home/pavel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:286:in `reverse_each'
        from /home/pavel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:286:in `resolve'
        from /home/pavel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:336:in `block in resolve_requirement'
        from /home/pavel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:335:in `catch'
        from /home/pavel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:335:in `resolve_requirement'
        from /home/pavel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:287:in `block in resolve'
        from /home/pavel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:286:in `reverse_each'
        from /home/pavel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:286:in `resolve'
        from /home/pavel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:336:in `block in resolve_requirement'
        from /home/pavel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:335:in `catch'
        from /home/pavel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:335:in `resolve_requirement'
        from /home/pavel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:287:in `block in resolve'
        from /home/pavel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:286:in `reverse_each'
        from /home/pavel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:286:in `resolve'
        from /home/pavel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:336:in `block in resolve_requirement'
        from /home/pavel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:335:in `catch'
        from /home/pavel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:335:in `resolve_requirement'
        from /home/pavel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:287:in `block in resolve'
        from /home/pavel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:286:in `reverse_each'
        from /home/pavel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:286:in `resolve'
        from /home/pavel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:336:in `block in resolve_requirement'
        from /home/pavel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:335:in `catch'
        from /home/pavel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:335:in `resolve_requirement'
        from /home/pavel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:287:in `block in resolve'
        from /home/pavel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:286:in `reverse_each'
        from /home/pavel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:286:in `resolve'
        from /home/pavel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:336:in `block in resolve_requirement'
        from /home/pavel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:335:in `catch'
        from /home/pavel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:335:in `resolve_requirement'
        from /home/pavel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:287:in `block in resolve'
        from /home/pavel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:286:in `reverse_each'
        from /home/pavel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:286:in `resolve'
        from /home/pavel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:336:in `block in resolve_requirement'
        from /home/pavel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:335:in `catch'
        from /home/pavel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:335:in `resolve_requirement'
        from /home/pavel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:287:in `block in resolve'
        from /home/pavel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:286:in `reverse_each'
        from /home/pavel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:286:in `resolve'
        from /home/pavel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:336:in `block in resolve_requirement'
        from /home/pavel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:335:in `catch'
        from /home/pavel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:335:in `resolve_requirement'
        from /home/pavel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:287:in `block in resolve'
        from /home/pavel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:286:in `reverse_each'
        from /home/pavel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:286:in `resolve'
        from /home/pavel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:160:in `start'
        from /home/pavel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:128:in `block in resolve'
        from /home/pavel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:127:in `catch'
        from /home/pavel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:127:in `resolve'
        from /home/pavel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/definition.rb:151:in `resolve'
        from /home/pavel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/definition.rb:90:in `specs'
        from /home/pavel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/definition.rb:85:in `resolve_remotely!'
        from /home/pavel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/installer.rb:43:in `run'
        from /home/pavel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/installer.rb:8:in `install'
        from /home/pavel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/cli.rb:219:in `install'
        from /home/pavel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/task.rb:22:in `run'
        from /home/pavel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/invocation.rb:118:in `invoke_task'
        from /home/pavel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/vendor/thor.rb:263:in `dispatch'
        from /home/pavel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/base.rb:386:in `start'
        from /home/pavel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/bundler-1.0.21/bin/bundle:13:in `<top (required)>'
        from /home/pavel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/bundle:19:in `load'
        from /home/pavel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/bundle:19:in `<main>'
```

My Gemfile looks like this:

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.0.9'
gem 'compass'
gem 'haml-rails'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'authlogic'
gem 'russian', '~> 0.6.0'
gem 'facebooker'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

group :assets do
  gem 'sass', '~>3.1'
  #gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'

  # See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
  # gem 'therubyracer'

  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end
gem 'mysql2', '< 0.3'

# Use unicorn as the web server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Deploy with Capistrano
# gem 'capistrano'

# To use debugger (ruby-debug for Ruby 1.8.7+, ruby-debug19 for Ruby 1.9.2+)
# gem 'ruby-debug'
# gem 'ruby-debug19', :require => 'ruby-debug'

# Bundle the extra gems:
# gem 'bj'
# gem 'nokogiri'
# gem 'sqlite3-ruby', :require => 'sqlite3'
# gem 'aws-s3', :require => 'aws/s3'

# Bundle gems for the local environment. Make sure to
# put test-only gems in this group so their generators
# and rake tasks are available in development mode:
# group :development, :test do
#   gem 'webrat'
# end
```

try to install rails facebooker to my authlogic gems from here https://github.com/kalasjocke/authlogic_facebook_connect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend RVM and creating a fresh gemset
[RVM](https://rvm.io)

Comment: updating bundler would be my next step.

Comment: no when try bundle update ger the same list of bla bla bla text/(